# What should I study to prepare for Stochastic Calculus

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, stochastic-calculus, education, advice

Context, I am an undergrad looking to take graduate stochastic calculus next semester. Unfortunately I do not have a whole lot of experience with probability theory as a whole. I've taken a first course in graduate probability theory (up to CLT and LLN) and have a decent measure theory background. I've spoken to the instructor, he has agreed to let me take the class and has also agreed to slow down the first few classes so that we (me and a couple other undergraduate students) don't immediately get lost. He suggests that I learn as much as I can about Markov processes and martingales to get myself used to the type of theorems that I will be seeing.

I have two books, Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course by Achim Klenke, and Probability: Theory and Examples by Rick Durrett. The former of which I have read and done exercises for up to and including chapter 15 (skipping chapters 10,11,12 on martingales).

I would be very grateful if someone could suggest what else I need to be familiar with before going into the course (I'm already planning on finishing all sections on Markov processes and martingales in Klenke)? And in particular, could someone take a quick look at the table of contents of one of the books and let me know if there's any chapters I don't really need to read.

Comment: Normally, some real analysis and measure theory would be useful

Comment: ‘ I am an undergrad looking to take graduate stochastic calculus next semester. Unfortunately I do not have a whole lot of experience with probability theory as a whole.’ You might want to consider, and elucidate upon, what is motivating you to do stochastic calculus before having an understanding of probability basics. And why ‘unfortunately’?

Comment: Unfortunately as in stochastic calculus is offered every other year and so if I don't take it now I'll have to take it in 3 years, yet I technically  do not have the experience to take it.